# UITableViewCell's image change when cell is selected

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have an `UIImageView` set as the background to a custom cell (prototype cell) .How can I change the image in the image view , when the cell is selected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to change the image of the imageview on cell selection then you will need to do it in delegate method of tableview here:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{}
```

If you have a custom cell and you have set its background as an image view then you must also create its property in custom cell's class and change the image of the image view through that property in the mentioned delegate.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try the property highlightedImage ?